# Combining results from Split()

Tags: asp-classic

I am having the following issue:

The following string is retrieved through linked tables in an MS Access DB:

```
string = Text1, Text2, Text3, "This, belongs, together", Text7, Text8, "This, Also, Belongs, Together", Text13, etc., etc., etc.
```

The quoted fields can vary in how long they are.

When i use a Split(string, ",") it returns 13 values now, and the quotes i can remove with a replace no problem. 
The problem i am facing is that the text between the quotes should be 1 value.
In the above example that would mean i should get 8 values instead of the 13. This is needed for an INSERT INTO query to the database.

Here is what i got so far which gives the error:
Subscript out of range: 'i'

```
SqlJunk = "SELECT * FROM Con_Temp" 
Set rsCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsCon.Open SqlJunk, dbGlobalWeb, 3

Do While Not rsCon.EOF
Field = split(rsCon("Field1"),",")
For i = 0 to UBound(Field)
    If InStr(Field(i),"""") > 0 Then
        Field(i) = Replace(Field(i), """", "")
    End if
    If Field(i) <> "" Then
        If dbfields <> "" Then
            dbfields = dbfields & ",[" & Conveldnaam(i) & "]"
        Else
            dbfields = "[" & Conveldnaam(i) & "]"
        End if
        If dbvalues <> "" Then
            dbvalues = dbvalues & ",""" & Field(i) & """"
        Else
            dbvalues = """" & Field(i) & """"
        End if
    End if
    response.write(dbfields)
Next
SQL = "INSERT INTO ConInventory (" & dbfields & ") VALUES (" & dbvalues & ")"
response.write(SQL & "<br>")
dbGlobalWeb.Execute(SQL)
rsCon.MoveNext
dbfields = ""
dbvalues = ""
Loop
```

Any thoughts how i could combine the values within the quotes?

Thanks in advance!

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic and modify your code accordingly:-

```
Dim str, strArray, count, combineStr
count = 0
combineStr = ""
str = "Text1, Text2, Text3, ""This, belongs, together"", Text7, Text8, ""This, Also, Belongs, Together"", Text13"
strArray = split(str, ", ")


For Each item In strArray
    If (Left(item, 1) = """") Then
        combineStr = combineStr & " " & item
        count = 1
    ElseIf (count = 1) Then
        If (Right(item, 1) = """") Then
            count = 0
        End If
        combineStr = combineStr & " " & item
    End If
    If (count = 0) Then
        If (combineStr = "") Then
            Response.Write("<br>" & item)
        ElseIf (combineStr <> "") Then
            Response.Write("<br>" & combineStr)
            combineStr = ""
        End If
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks a million! Had to make some very minor adjustments to implement it (like you said) but have it working for about 90% now! You just made my day, thanks again!